# Цвет фона Pane у NavigationView в UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp

Я хочу что бы цвет был такой же белезны как на первой фотографии как бы я не пытался изменить цвет на более белее ничего не выходило можно поставить TintOpacity на 1 но в итоге блюра не будет вообще просто белый фон, а если поставить TintOpacity на 0.99 то будет серый

Этот код я добавил в ресурсы страницы

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
      BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="White" TintOpacity="0.99" TintLuminosityOpacity="0.5"/>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

[image: первая картинка]
[image: моë приложение]

Comment: Вы поставили метку UWP, но на скринах у вас пример из Winodws App SDK (WinUI 3). К сожалению, я не знаю, как это сделать в UWP, знаю только как в WinUI 3 и это решение вам не подойдёт. В любом случае, это не фон, это Backdrop называется.

Comment: @aepot но это работает у меня в UWP с установкой пакета Windows.Xaml.UI.Controls да я знаю что это Backdrop и я научился менять цвет как я и показал таким образом он меняется, но он по дефолту темнее

Comment: В самом WinUI 3 Gallery есть пример System Backdrop. Исходники есть на гитхабе https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/SamplePages/SampleBuiltInSystemBackdropsWindow.xaml.cs, а как это делается в WinUI 2 на UWP, я не в курсе, попробуйте поискать WinUI 2 Gallery в винсторе, возможно там есть пример.

Comment: @aepot а в uwp  нельзя установить WinUI 3?

Comment: Вопрос звучит так же как "А в Windows 10 нельзя установить Windows 11?". UWP это WinUI 2 по своей сути.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код поможет вам если вы хотите изменить цвет блюра-фона у Pane у NavigationView UWP и теперь он не становиться темнее и всë работает корректно

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <!-- The "Default" theme dictionary is used unless a specific
                         light, dark, or high contrast dictionary is provided. These
                         resources should be tested with both the light and dark themes,
                         and specific light or dark resources provided as needed. -->
                    <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                           BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
                           TintColor="White"
                           TintOpacity=".99"/>
                    <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewTopPaneBackground"
                           BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
                           TintColor="White"
                           TintOpacity=".6"/>
                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                             StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                    <!-- Always include a "HighContrast" dictionary when you override
                         theme resources. This empty dictionary ensures that the
                         default high contrast resources are used when the user
                         turns on high contrast mode. -->
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```